# How to Restrict a Union Literal Type to One of the Literal Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I want to create a type predicate so that when I use `filter` on array of Union of generics, it would return the correct type.

I wrote a type to indicate the input/output type of the convert function for the corresponding id:

```
type ConverterGroupIdToFunc = {
  text: [string, string]
  image: [File, string]
}

type ConverterGroupId = keyof ConverterGroupIdToFunc

type ConverterGroup<T extends ConverterGroupId> = {
  id: T
  convertFunc: (s: ConverterGroupIdToFunc[T][0]) => (ConverterGroupIdToFunc[T][1]);
}
```

And I also need a ConverterGroup array to store 2 different types of generics `(ConverterGroup<"text">|ConverterGroup<"image">)[]`

```
type ConverterGroupUnion = ConverterGroup<"text"> | ConverterGroup<"image">
```

For `converterGroups: (ConverterGroup<"text">|ConverterGroup<"image">)[]`, I'd like `find()` to return type `ConverterGroup<"text">` if the converterGroup's `id` is also `"text"`.

I am trying to use a type predicate to tell `find()` to return the correct type but couldn't find how:

```
function isConverterGroup<T extends ConverterGroupId>(converterGroupId: T) {
  return (converterGroup: ConverterGroupUnion): converterGroup is ConverterGroup<T> => {
    return converterGroup.id === converterGroupId;
  }
}

const convertFunc = converterGroups.find(isConverterGroup("text"))!.convertFunc;
```

The above code gives me the error:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'ConverterGroup<T>' is not assignable to type 'ConverterGroupUnion'.
    Type 'ConverterGroup<T>' is not assignable to type 'ConverterGroup<"text">'.
      Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"text"'.ts(2677)
```

Here is the [Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCKwGYEsB2qAuqD26AoLGeAYXwDdYAnLGgcWtwFdoBJAE3FwDFn0AxqAC8oAN4FQoOgA8sALlABtAM5ZqGAOYAaUGo3pNAXUmhUAWwCGm2IqU9UAG1i79WkwF8CREqHLoqWgYmVk4RUABrWEhcZD9KGjpqRhZ2Ll5%20AR84eIDE4NSAVUx8cP9ApJTWAB4AIlksWoA%20UAAfXIqCmtqLa1hm72yyBKDkkOhq8FBYOVh0DhUO-LHUzhbRCSlUDkVwUwERrD5BRQAKFUVy5aq07mOBJXAjJQAGIwBKERbTq9GbzjumUezwAjB8ANwELwEZCZHClVAqX6VcaTaazeaLZFdNJNU4HPJ-cacXafTagaiwLDMajoUD4w44y6MlasYp4dDvRQEzqs6BmLEsm6TdYtclSSnU2mgHnXcYAOm2ImEollRNWHEhUi80IIIFAhRUfQIBLUMqF4wuS3VbJK6CURnCSlM4rMO1A9RmjW0pikaqOmUUbkM3AAQpYVLAAGwAFlMHh9Uld20UPSsNlqiak5sJAZOoA4zHM5kgDmc3AAyuotPGCCYTfgzf77uF-TiVPK0PNTojsXzTp65LV3u8AITy5uZSGDGfeWGCeF0wvF0tOWCV6uGU7IRRl2BcvSbzTiUySml0gDkF6hc7hHMPBk0YYj0Zjp1wGk0GEsjirj6DR5kvsjZYKAzAYFgAAcACC1DUJYkDhOgsAAO4QF6ACigi4BwNCnO88pzAcuHvp%2036-oBWo5maABGGB-lo4QMYYnZMOY5C4QACrgEGnPK-GwfBkCsbg5inOB6BQYJCEjlRZ7SjRWC4JYpx0egzGaO8kIeEAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NloVOw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (although I have no react knowledge and it doesn't seem like the question really depends on it... a [mre] really should have the minimal stuff needed to demonstrate the issue, so you might want to spend some time [edit]ing this down). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Great! It works! Sure I can edit my question down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you know that a type `X` is assignable to a type `Y`, but TypeScript can't see it because either `X` or `Y` depend on some [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.  In your example, `ConverterGroup<T>` is generic and the compiler can't figure out that it's assignable to `ConverterGroupUnion`. And since a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) requires that for `y is X` the type `X` is assignable to `typeof y`, it complains with `converterGroup is ConverterGroup<T>`.

In situations like this, you can usually fix it by changing `X` to either `X & Y` or `Extract<X, Y>` or `Extract<Y, X>` depending on the use case. An [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is always assignable to its members, and so is the result of the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)-filtering [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  If you're right that `X` is assignable to `Y`, then eventually `X & Y` and `Extract<X, Y>` (and maybe `Extract<Y, X>`, depending on the form of `Y` and `X`) will be just `X` once the generic is specified, and the resulting behavior doesn't change. If you're wrong about the assignability then you'll end up with something else, possibly [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so you should be careful that you know what you're doing with the types.

Anyway since in your case it looks like you just want to filter the `ConverterGroupUnion` to the member that is assignable to `ConverterGroup<T>`, you can use `Extract<ConverterGroupUnion, ConverterGroup<T>>`:

```
function isConverterGroup<T extends ConverterGroupId>(converterGroupId: T) {
  return (converterGroup: ConverterGroupUnion):
    converterGroup is Extract<ConverterGroupUnion, ConverterGroup<T>> => {
    return converterGroup.id === converterGroupId;
  }
}
```

Now there's no error, and your other code works as expected:

```
const convertFunc = converterGroups.find(isConverterGroup("text"))!.convertFunc;
// const convertFunc: (s: string) => string
```

Note that if you did something weird like

```
const x = isConverterGroup(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "text" : "image");
// const x: (converterGroup: ConverterGroupUnion) => converterGroup is never
```

You get that `never` I was mentioning, because `ConverterGroup<"text" | "image">` is not related to either `ConverterGroup<"text">` or `ConverterGroup<"image">`, since `ConverterGroup<T>` is *invariant* in `T` (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)).  Which is part of the reason for the error in the first place.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCKwGYEsB2qAuqD26AoLGeAYXwDdYAnLGgcWtwFdoBJAE3FwDFn0AxqAC8oAN4FQoOgA8sALlABtAM5ZqGAOYAaUGo3pNAXUmhUAWwCGm2IqU9UAG1i79WkwF8CREqHLoqWgYmVk4RUABrWEhcZD9KGjpqRhZ2Ll5+AR84eIDE4NSAVUx8cP9ApJTWAB4AIlksWoA+UAAfXIqCmtqLa1hm72yyBKDkkOhq8FBYOVh0DhUO-LHUzhbRCSlUDkVwUwERrD5BRQAKFUVy5aq07mOBJXAjJQAGIwBKERbTq9GbzjumUezwAjB8ANwELwEZCZHClVAqX6VcaTaazeaLZFdNJNU4HPJ-cacXafTagaiwLDMajoUD4w44y6MlasYp4dDveSmKQEzqs6BmRYAUTk1EsAiw1WxAvZ+F0Mpukya6xa5KklOptNAfOu4wAdNsRMJRLqiasOJCpF5oQQQKBCio+gQCWodSybhclua2SV0EojOElKZ1WYdqB6jNGtoee7CUdMoo3IZuAAhSwqWAANgALKYPDGpKHtooelYbLVC1I4xV7ooOMxzOZIA5nNwAMrqLT5ggmF34N1mhOCcJDnEqfVoeanRGK8anSNyWrvd4AQn1Q-ukO8rqwoBk4VnHvnAFlLFgABb68XzXDmU6faqgF76gCsoAA-BGGrVQKXehW7yQvau77mcY4Csy8Y4nKnJfDWeqpEKoDoLAgSDBhsKCPCdINk2LZOLAHZdoYpzIIorawFyegkZo4imJqNJ0gA5MxULeFhkocjRBiaGmGbZjmpy4BomgYJYjidrxSa0WS+wDnuzAYFgAAcACC1DipA4SoQA7hAUbCoIuAcDQD76nMBymcJoniZJslWnGboAEYYFJWjhO5hiTkw5jkKZAAKuDKac+phRpWk+XepxKegqkRZYkAro5jHas5WC4JYpyuegXmaEBUJAA)